# Flutter Android Alarm Manager plugin does not work properly

Tags: android, flutter, dart, alarmmanager

in my flutter app I am trying to run a function in background every minute. I used android alarm manager plugin, when calling `AndroidAlarmManager.periodic` function with 1-minute interval alarm fires correctly at every minute. but sometimes the function runs after random delay.

output:

```
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:0:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:1:20
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:2:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:3:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:4:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:5:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:6:40
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:7:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:8:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:9:20
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:10:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:11:0
I/flutter ( 4130): Alarm Fired at: 16:12:0
```

I am using alarm manger plugin version 0.4.5+17

I tried increasing interval time to 5 minutes and 10 minutes still the same issue occurs.

my code:

```dart
void alarmCallback() {
  print(
      'Alarm Fired at: ${DateTime.now().hour}:${DateTime.now().minute}:${DateTime.now().second}');
}

void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());

  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

  final int alarmId = 1;

  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(
    Duration(minutes: 1),
    alarmId,
    alarmCallback,
    exact: true,
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you won't have much luck with the android alarm manager plugin. The alarm gets invoked on time, but then it sends the work to a service, and android will actually run the service when it's convenient for android.

I have ended up with writing my own java code for scheduling the alarm and I am running only native android code (no dart code) in my BroadcastReceiver.